# Applying AOP for JDK classes

Tags: spring, aop, java

I want to have a pointcut + advice for JDK method `System.currentTimeMillis()` in order to return a customized value for the timestamp. I would like to know whether is this possible in Spring framework.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. In order to do this you need to instrument the JDK using AspectJ and create your own, custom JDK version. Spring AOP can only proxy Spring beans. Alternative approaches via `java.lang.instrument` and tools like BCEL or ASM might also work.

BTW: I am around 90% sure that there is an easier way to achieve what you want. Can you explain why you want to falsify the results of a system function?

Comment: Simply I just need to time shifted testing for my application which runs in JBOSS app server. I have tried the approach described in this link ( ttp://virgo47.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/changing-system-time-in-java/ t ) but it changes the time of the whole JVM hence even the app server get confused.

I only need to shift the time in my application. Therefore I have tried the date factory method but 3rd party libraries used in the application might have used the JDK provided time directly. So that is why I have come to this AOP thing. Any help is highly appriciated