# Aspect Not working with Completable Future

Tags: java, multithreading, aspectj, spring-aop, completable-future

I have a list of Consumers which I want to run in multiple threads. I have an aspect for logging and handling all the exceptions. Below is the code snippet.

The problem is that the aspect works fine till the point multiple threads are not created. After that in case of exception (`@LogFailure`) code doesn't enter the advice.

```
@Override
public void consumerExecutor(Map<Consumer<IProcessDTO>, IProcessDTO> map, IContext context) {
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator consumerIterator = map.keySet().iterator();

    while (consumerIterator.hasNext()) {
        Consumer<IProcessDTO> consumer = (Consumer<IProcessDTO>) consumerIterator.next();
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            executeSingleConsumer(0, consumer,map.get(consumer));
        });
        completableFutures.add(future);
    }

    try {
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]));
        allFuturesResult.thenApply(v ->
                completableFutures.stream().
                        map(future -> future.join()).
                        collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    } catch (CancellationException | CompletionException exception) {
       
    }
}


@LogFailure
@LogSuccess
private void executeSingleConsumer(int tries, Consumer<IProcessDTO> consumer,IProcessDTO processDto) {
    try {
        consumer.accept(null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (tries < maxAttempts) {
            executeSingleConsumer(tries + 1, consumer,processDto);
        } else if (tries == maxAttempts) {
            throw new ProcessException();
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}



@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(@com.LogFailure * *.*(..))", argNames = "jp,ex", throwing = "ex")
public void handleLogFailure(JoinPoint jp, Exception ex) {
    // exceptions handled
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you are using Spring AOP rather than native AspectJ, which is why in this case you cannot intercept private methods. What happens if you make the method public?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring AOP. I tried making the method public but it didn't help.

Comment: Then please share a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem, ideally a Maven project on GitHub. Gradle is also OK. There are many possible reasons, and I want to avoid speculating. I prefer analysing, like every software developer.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460180) the reason?